# Share HTML DOM audio element with THREE.AudioListener

Tags: three.js, html5-audio

I have a WebGL experience that has a component that reacts to the audio that is playing. We also have standard HTML DOM elements that need to listen to the audio so we can render subtitling.

In `THREE` we can create a `THREE.AudioListener` like this:

```
// create an AudioListener and add it to the camera
const listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );

// create a global audio source
const sound = new THREE.Audio( listener );

// load a sound and set it as the Audio object's buffer
const audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
audioLoader.load( 'sounds/ambient.ogg', function( buffer ) {
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setLoop(true);
    sound.setVolume(0.5);
    sound.play();
});
```

Is there a way to get the audio source from the DOM instead of loading it with the `THREE.AudioLoader`? Or tell the `THREE.AudioListener` to listen for the audio from the DOM element instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Three.js `Audio` object (and all its related classes) use the [WebAudio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API). I believe you can get the WebAudio context via the [`Audio.context` property](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=audio#api/en/audio/Audio.context), which gives you access to any native WebAudio command.

Secondly, based on the "Loading Sound" section [from this demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API#loading_sound), it looks like you can select an `<audio>` tag and pass it to the WebAudio API via `createMediaElementSource()`:

```js
// create a global audio source
const listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );
const audio = new THREE.Audio( listener );

// Get WebAudio context
const audioContext = audio.context;

// get the <audio> element
const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');

// pass it into the audio context
const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
```

#### Edit:

I just realized Three.js already does this for you without accessing the context manually via [the `Audio.setMediaElementSource` method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=audio#api/en/audio/Audio.setMediaElementSource), so you could skip a step:

```js
// create a global audio source
const listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );
const audio = new THREE.Audio( listener );

// get the <audio> element
const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
const track = audio.setMediaElementSource(audioElement);
```

Comment: This makes me happy. Thank you.

Comment: I just added an edit at the bottom, I discovered Three.js allows this out of the box, without having to access the Audio.context property.

Comment: An absolute star. Thanks. 